# Windows PowerShell Script to convert a folder of Word Docs to PDF

Tags: windows, powershell

So I already have the basic code to do this. i.e. convert a folder of word docs to pdf.

```
# Acquire a list of DOCX files in a folder

$Files=GET-CHILDITEM ‘C:\Users\Ashley\downloads\articles\*.DOC’
$Word=NEW-OBJECT –COMOBJECT WORD.APPLICATION


Foreach ($File in $Files) {

    # open a Word document, filename from the directory

    $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

    # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename

    $Name=($Doc.Fullname).replace(“doc”,”pdf”)

    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.saveas([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
    $Doc.close()

}
```

But as it stands if I have docx files. I need to re run the code replacing doc with docx.
Is their any way I can make the replace function replace doc and docx for pdf? Thus eliminating the need to re run it twice? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help. Notice get-childitem looks for doc*, and the regex in the replace.

```
$Files=GET-CHILDITEM 'C:\Users\Ashley\downloads\articles\*.DOC*'
$Word=NEW-OBJECT –COMOBJECT WORD.APPLICATION

Foreach ($File in $Files) {

    # open a Word document, filename from the directory

    $Doc=$Word.Documents.Open($File.fullname)

    # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename

    $Name=$Doc.Fullname -replace('doc([x]{0,1})',"pdf")

    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.saveas([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
    $Doc.close()

}
```

Comment: I get the error Exception calling "SaveAs" with "16" argument(s): "Command failed"
At line:17 char:16
+     $Doc.saveas <<<< ([ref] $Name, [ref] 17)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: I edited the code, and used -replace. I was then able to save to a pdf file.

Comment: Hi @Micky Balladelli, I am using your script to convert several docx files, but failed with the error:  parameter “1” should not be System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Please don't use [ref]. Can you spot why? I am using PS 2 on Windows 7.

Comment: @WayneCui It could be a difference in the version of Word? What is the method SaveAs expecting in your case?